# Subclass' __getitem__ returns unexpected slice

Tags: python, python-2.7, subclass, slice

I have created a class that subclasses ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser to implement sectionless config files. The problem I'm having is I get an unexpected slice type back compared to how I expect `__getitem__` to respond:

```
import ConfigParser

class foo(ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser):
    def __getitem__(self, option):
        return option

class bar(object):
    def __getitem__(self,option):
        return option

a = foo()
b = bar()
print a[:]
print b[:]
```

Its reply puzzles me, as I get:

```
slice(0, 2147483647, None)
slice(None, None, None)
```

I would have expected `(None, None, None)` in both cases.  I can *guess* its behavior is familiar--if for example I was working with a simple `list()` slicing action--but this makes it especially hard to determine the user's intent via `if option.start is None`, which fails in the former case.

What part of `SafeConfigParser` is changing this behavior and what can I do to receive `(None, None, None)` instead of `(0, sys.maxint, None)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SafeConfigParser` is an old-style class, and therefore so is your `foo`. Your `bar` is a new-style class (derived from `object`).

```
>>> type(ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser)
<type 'classobj'>

>>> type(foo)
<type 'classobj'>

>>> type(bar)
<type 'type'>
```

Old-style classes have a number of differences from new-style ones; clearly, this is one of them, presumably for backward compatibility (i.e. because that's how slicing used to behave). It has nothing to do with `SafeConfigParser` *per se,* as you can see here:

```
class baz:    # old-style class in Python 2.x where x >= 2
    def __getitem__(self, option):
        return option

c = baz()
print c[:]    # slice(0, 2147483647, None)
```

To get around this I guess you could try to update `ConfigParser` to use new-style classes. This may be reasonably easy; a diff with Python 3's `configparser` (which does not use old-style clasess, because there's no such thing in Python 3) might be helpful.

Comment: It should have occurred to me it was related to old-style classes, as I'd painfully discovered how much sub-classing `SafeConfigParser` didn't care for `@property`, either. I'll take a look at Python 3's and perhaps it'll lead me in the right direction--thanks!